# A question about the definition of a subbasis in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres Topology he defined a subbasis for a topology on $X$ as a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$.

Does this imply that a subbasis could contain a closed subset of $X$  as an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. There is no restriction that a set be either open or closed but not both, for instance. Consider the discrete topology on $X = \{0,1\}$ given by $\tau = \{\{0\},\{1\},\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}$. Then the set $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$ is a subbasis, but of course both of the elements of this subbasis are both open and closed in the topology generated by the subbasis.

Comment: ok but could we not find a collection of subsets of X such that each subset is closed but not open, and the union of the closed sets are X. Then we would have a subbasis full of non open sets.

Comment: I understand now.... in the topology generated by my subbasis the non closed sets that I started with to build my subbasis will be open in my new topology?


So If I have a topology on X, and I get a subbasis for some topology on X, these topologies might not be the same. In fact I can say for sure that if a subbasis element is closed in some topology then that subbasis will NOT generate the same topology. I think.

Answer (score 1):

When discussing topology, you need to sepecify closed or open in which topology. A subbasis for $\mathcal{T}_1$ can certainly contain closed set in topology $\mathcal{T}_2$. Also please note open set is not "door", that is a set can be both open and closed in certain topology. Just consider discrete topology as an example.